# How to allow only numbers on a text input but allow commands with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When searching for ways to allow only numbers on a text input you usually get something like:

```
function keyPressEvent (e) {
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that this makes keys that only do commands not work. Starting with <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd>, but even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>f5</kbd>. I know I can create exceptions for all of this, but I think this will be a waste of time. Is there some easy way to do what I want? Is there something like detecting the character that will be added to the text, and not the key pressed?

Comment: you could do what they suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950208/textbox-with-alphanumeric-check-in-javascript for alpha characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually went for an approach where I let the user type / enter whatever they want to, and manually coerce the value to be a numeric.  Something like this (it's a jQuery project, but the idea can easily be re-used w/o jQuery).

```
fieldJq.bind('click keyup change blur focus', function (ev) {
  var curVal = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(curVal.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
});
```

The idea here being that I'm letting them put whatever they want to into it (so there's no chance of breaking control commands like copy / paste, etc) but after any value change to it I remove anything that's not a digit or a decimal point.  It's not 100% fireproof at this point (10.0.0 isn't invalid) but it does come close initially at least.  If you didn't need floating point support and could remove the `\.` from the regex you'd have an enforced numeric input.

Comment: I guess this is the best answer at this point and that meanwhile I should just wait for the number input type to be implemented in most browsers. Thank anyway!

Comment: In IE7 it always puts cursor to the end, can be fixed by checking before replace:
if (curVal.search(/[^0-9\.]/g)>-1)