# How to do validation for text box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, validation

I need to do validation for text with the following conditions.

- Numerics are not allowed.
- The allowed characters are: A-Z, a-z, apostrophe, space and hyphen.
- Does not contain Suffix

I am new to `.Net` and JavaScript. Can someone suggest how to do it?

Comment: What is your issue here? Do you have any code that you have tried? Please note that this is not `Give me some code for` site. We can try to help with any specific issue you have.

Comment: I am doing something like below.    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('input.alpha[$id=tb1]'.bind('keyup blur', function() {
if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
}
});
});
</script>

Comment: Visit the 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950208/textbox-with-alphanumeric-check-in-javascript

It will give you basic Idea of validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code in your "keyup blur" event handler

```
$(function() {
    $('input.alpha[$id=tb1]'.bind('keyup blur', function() {
        if (this.value.search(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/) === -1) {
          alert("Only valid characters present");
        }
     }); 
});
```

Use + instead of * if you don't want to allow empty matches for regex.